# Submit Facebook App for review before iOS App is released to public?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.1

I've developed an iOS app which includes the Facebook SDK to post Open Graph user stories to Facebook. Everything is working fine, so I sent my iOS app yesterday to Apple for review.

But my problem is the Facebook app:
I have to submit the Facebook app for review, so that it can be used by the public. However I can't submit it, because Facebook can't access my iOS App by the App-ID in iTunes store. See the following error message:

[image]

If I insert an App-ID from any public app (e.g. Whatsapp) I can save my changes and I am able to submit the Facebook App.

My fear is that if my iOS app comes to the App Store and the Facebook feature doesn't work, I'll receive bad ratings from users.

So my question is: Is there any way to send my Facebook app for review without my iOS app being released to the public?

// EDIT according to Björn Kaisers answer:
I want to submit only my Open Graph story, but the problem is that I have to add screenshots. If I click on "Add Screenshots" a popup opens and I have to select the platform, but I can't select the iOS platform that I added in the settings (it's not visible) because it has no iPhone Store ID.
Again if I add (for testing) an iPhone Store ID from a public app (e.g. Whatsapp), I'm able to select the iOS platform to add screenshots.

See here:
[image]

And without these screenshots I can't submit for review :( It's a doom loop.

UPDATE 29.01.2014:
As proposed I selected "Webseite" as platform and uploaded screenshots from using Facebook in my iOS App in hope that the Facebook reviewers would understand that the screenshots are showing an iOS App, but today I failed review:
[image]

Comment: What you could consider is to upload your app, make it available to some small corner of the world. Then sort out the facebook review. Once the facebook review is ok make your app available to the right regions/world. It is a horrible workaround but might just get you what you need. (I am not sure, because I am still dealing with a similar issue as well)

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. But I can't understand how a world company like Facebook provides such a bad workflow

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about App Store policies and not about programming.

Answer (score 20):

To submit an unreleased iOS App for Review, you will need to submit the simulator binary version through the submission form. Read the tutorial [Creating iOS Simulator Build for Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/advanced#sim_build) to get more details. In short, make sure that the selected platform is iOS, then find the following section:

[image]

And then upload your binary through the dialog:

[image]

Comment: Well, it's available now, and users looking for an answer will find the solution helpful.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  This and the link you provided were EXACTLY what I needed, and you should never have been down voted before.

Comment: What happens when the my app wont work on the simulator? For different reasons the key features of the app require a device.

Comment: Just a general thought, maybe you could mock those out and in your description write that specific features have been mocked to enable testing on a simulator.

Comment: As a Unity developer, this doesn't work for me since Unity cannot generate simulator build when I using Facebook Unity SDK.....